# ASP.NET - How do I hide javascript from IE?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have some Google Plus One javascript in my .ASCX file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
</script>
```

I need to hide this bit of code from IE7 and IE8 browsers.

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Markup Method

```
<%  If Not (Page.Request.Browser.Browser.StartsWith("IE", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) AndAlso Page.Request.Browser.MajorVersion < 9) Then%>
This is either Not IE, or IE 9 or greater<br />
<% end if %>
```

## Code-Behind Method

Just Put the Script Inside PlaceHolder & Set Its visibility to true/false. Use to following function to detect browser in asp.net.

```
public static bool IsIE(Page page)
{
  if (page != null && page.Request != null && page.Request.Browser != null)
  {
    return page.Request.Browser.Browser.StartsWith("IE", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && (page.Request.Browser.MajorVersion == 7 || page.Request.Browser.MajorVersion == 8);
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: This is not a reliable way to do things.  Many browsers have modes that 'emulate' IE and send IE User Agent strings.  This will also hide the code from them as well.

Comment: If they want to emulate IE8 or IE7, then I do not think they should see code that is hidden from IE8 or IE7.

Comment: Also, taking a step back, why are you trying to hide this stuff from IE 7 and 8 users?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to do this, if you are already including jQuery, you could use its browser sniffing functions.  The other option is you could use IE conditional comments: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if !(IE 7)&!(IE 8)]>
You are not using IE7 or IE8
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: "You are not using IE7 or IE8" will not render on Firefox, Chrome, or Safari. I believe with this method, my code must include the script twice. Reference: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html